# How to get information via POST request without reloading entire webpage. (Python/Django)

Tags: python, html, django, http, web-applications

The situation is simply that we want to send information to Django (our web framework), have it perform functions on the information, and receive information back from Django.

Just now our form to POST to the server looks like this.

```
<form method="post" onAction="/write" name="form1">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">Send Info for processing</button>
</form>
```

And we want this process to send a variable or transmit information.

This successfully reaches our `views.py` and gets to a function where information can be done.

But currently we don't know how to take information in from the POST nor how to send it back without loading a whole new page.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want to refresh the page when you are posting a request, you would want to make a Asynchronous Request to the Server. JQuery, Javascript library has some neat functions which would help you make an asynchronous request. After the server receives the request, it can perform computation can send an HttpResponse with HTML, XML or JSON data as mentioned by Brandon

This is a wiki page for the Tutorial on Ajax with Django

https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AJAX

Comment: But won't the HttpResponse content just overwrite what the browser parses as the source code of the page?

Comment: No, it won't. Since, you would receive the response in your javascript function

Comment: Just added code to JS meant to handle response and sent `return HttpResponse("hey")` but it does what I was worried about in a previous comment, it simply shows a page with source code "Hey" and nothing else.

Comment: Looks like either you are not making an AJAX Request or the response is not appropriate. Please post the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return an HttpResponse. It's up to you whether or not to return XML, JSON, HTML, etc. Your request has to be made via Ajax.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse

Comment: In a similar reply to the other answer, won't the HttpResponse content just overwrite what the browser parses as the source code of the page?

Comment: No. The response is received by JavaScript. It's up to you to prcess the response and update the DOM as you need.

Comment: Just added code to JS meant to handle response and sent `return HttpResponse("hey")` but it does what I was worried about in a previous comment, it simply shows a page with source code "Hey" and nothing else.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm right about to head out for a while, but please see my Ajax Base Form snippets to get an idea how how to return and process an Ajax response: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2393/